# How to read the properties of the child object in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "name": "Top Bar After Login",
    "cid": "9921",
    "position": "26",
    "properties": [{
        "propname": "ITEMCOUNT",
        "propvalue": "0"
    }, {
        "propname": "Display",
        "propvalue": "yes"
    }],
    "childs": [{
        "name": "Santosh",
        "cid": "10299",
        "properties": [{
            "propname": "Display",
            "propvalue": "yes"
        }, {
            "propname": "ITEMCOUNT",
            "propvalue": "0"
        }],
        "childs": []
    }]
}
```

How to read the child's property in the above JSON object?

I have tried this example [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) but it didn't help me out to fetch child's properties.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: First of all you need to understand a difference between JSON and javascript object. You deal with plain javascript object. It's not JSON.

Comment: `var parsed_obj = { ... }; parsed_obj.properties[0]; parsed_obj.properties[1];` ?

Comment: Hi, I have 4 levels of sub categories. The above one I posted just for an example. Could you please tell me how I can fetch all the levels. Means data ={[childs={[childs={[childs{[childs={[]}]}]}]}]}   I am able to read first level of child properties

Comment: I am using this code to get the first level of child properties ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                          var count = Object.keys(data).length

for(var i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    alert("data"+data.childs[i].name);
    alert("data"+data.childs[i].cid);
}

Comment: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js is the solution for my above problem.

Comment: @  dfsq - it is JSON data which I am getting by hitting an URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do it like this?

```
var source = '{"name": "Top Bar After Login", "cid": "9921", "position": "26", "properties": [{"propname": "ITEMCOUNT","propvalue": "0"},{"propname": "Display", "propvalue": "yes"}],    "childs": [{"name": "Santosh","cid": "10299","properties": [{"propname": "Display", "propvalue": "yes" }, { "propname": "ITEMCOUNT", "propvalue": "0"}], "childs": [] }]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(source);
console.log( obj.childs[0].name ); //outputs Santosh
console.log( obj.name );            //Top Bar After Login 
console.log( obj.properties[0].propname,  obj.properties[0].propvalue ); //ITEMCOUNT 0
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hi, I have 4 levels of sub categories. The above one I posted just for an example. Could you please tell me how I can fetch all the levels. Means data ={[childs={[childs={[childs{[childs={[]}]}]}]}]}

Comment: obj.childs.childs.childs.childs[0].properties[0].propname or obj.childs[0].childs[0].childs[0].childs[0].properties[0].propname

But your sample code says obj.childs.childs

Comment: Hi 
Holger Thiebosch, Thanks for your help. Could you please help me in getting multiple levels of child properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your object above in a variable, say `parsed_obj` then you simply do

```
parsed_obj.properties[0];
```

to access its first property and

```
parsed_obj.properties[1];
```

for the second one.

Comment: Hi, I have 4 levels of sub categories. The above one I posted just for an example. Could you please tell me how I can fetch all the levels. Means data ={[childs={[childs={[childs{[childs={[]}]}]}]}]}

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "fetch all the level", but you can use dot notation to go as deep as you want, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators